# Proof with big $O$ notation

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics

How can I prove or refute

$ \log n \in O(2^{\log \log^{2}n}) $

I have the formal definition $O$ in my lecture notes:

$ \log n \in O(2^{\log \log^{2}n}) $
$ \Leftrightarrow  $ 
$ \exists c>0$  $\exists n_0: \forall n \ge n_0: $ $ 
\log(n)  \le c*2^{\log \log^{2}n}$

How to go keep going here?

Please any tips.

Thank you in anticipation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that $2^{\log z} = z$ if you are using binary logs (which I think you are). Then you must show
$$
\log n \in O(\log^2 n),
$$
can you finish this?

Comment: I will try it. I'm making it short: $ log n \in O(log^{2}n) $, $ \Leftrightarrow  $ :
$ log n \le c* log(n) * log(n) $  $ \Leftrightarrow  $ 
$ \frac{1}{logn} \le c $ 
So c has to be greater than $ \frac{1}{logn} $ 
is that right ?

Comment: @Blnpwr kind of, you indeed want $c \ge 1/\log N$ and take all $n > N$...

Comment: I did it with limes and showed the existence of the limit, which is 0. That is much more faster. Thank you very much!